# Invalid Heroku MFA Generated codes are invalid

Tags: heroku

I had Heroku MFA verification in the account. And everytime I would get the code via google authenticator. I had changed my laptop and ever since the code generated is invalid. I have tried to reset the laptop time and restoring the account but the issue is still persisting.Has anyone ever encountered the same issue,I know its not a big deal .

Comment: I mean, that sounds like a big deal to me. If you can't get valid MFA codes you're likely to get locked out of your account. I suggest you contact Heroku support immediately and get help resetting your MFA settings.

Comment: Mi think that was the only option, had decided not to since I have all the recovery thy not working

Answer (score 4):

This happens mainly if your phone and your desktop are not time synced; please turn on Automatic date and time on your mobile device and try again.

Comment: umm, this didnt work for me

Comment: Worked for me, thank you!